# Containers with the same image version but with different configs

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, containers, openshift

Is there a way to have an application with 2 containers with the same image version but with different name and resources on OpenShift?

For example: In the same namespace, given a micro service with set with replicas: 6, with the metada name "app-banking", I would like to have 3 pods with envs ABC and name "app-banking-aaa-<pod_hash>", and other 3 pods with name "app-banking-bbb<pod_hash> and envs VXZ.

Didn't find anything like this on the internet.

Since we have two Kafka Bootstraps-servers, we have some consumers services that we are trying to implement "cross-broker" solution, in the same namespace.

So 3 pods will have envs to connect to Bootstrap-Server1 and other 3 pods to Bootstrap-Server2.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: It's possible but you'll need to create 2 deployments for that. It's not possible to have one deployment with different configs.

Comment: I've read about DeploymentConfig, it's possible to achieve with this? Tks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy an application on OpenShift/Kubernetes, you need to create Deployments*1 resource on the cluster.

Deployments is one of the resources in Kubernetes and helps you to manage your application (Pod).
Deployments have fields to specify a container image url and environment variables. So that it is easy to deploy applications using same container images but using different environment variables. Here is an example.

Application app-baking-aaa-<pod_hash>

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-banking-aaa
  labels:
    app: app-banking-aaa
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-banking-aaa
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-banking-aaa
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-banking
        image: https://path-to-your-registry/your-app:tag1
        env:
        - name: ABC
          value: abc
```

Application app-banking-bbb-<pod_hash>

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-banking-bbb
  labels:
    app: app-banking-bbb
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-banking-bbb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-banking-bbb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-banking
        image: https://path-to-your-registry/your-app:tag1
        env:
        - name: VXZ
          value: vxz
```

You many need to add more fields on the deployment however, the above deployments could help you to understand what you need to do.

I think you also need to search ConfigMap and Secrets resource for defining environment variables in Deployments.

*1: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's possible with only one Deployment for the two configurations? I've read about DeploymentConfig but have doubts if it is effective.

Comment: @EdCwb Container is not a special technology so if you can implement the same configuration on a VM, it could be possible. 
As my understanding, you need to have two different type of applications, but the same binary, are required. Because the two applications access to different Kafka Clusters. 
So, I'd add the one more deployment on my answer.